# How do you fill a Byte header with empty characters?

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets

Im currently trying to add additional bytes to a byte array.

Im trying to send a header to a server that contains the computer name. However because the computer name could change for every machine im trying to create a byte array that is a specific length like 100 bytes.

Which means once i have my string header "rdmstream§" + Dns.GetHostName()" I need to add x amounts of bytes at the end or start as padding so the overall byte length = 100.

I was wondering if this was possible?

Below is an example of my code for having a set header length:

```
 public static void SendMultiScreen(byte[] img)
    {
        try
        {

            //string command = ("rdmstream§" + Dns.GetHostName()); //This is what I want to add.

            byte[] send = new byte[img.Length + 16]; //Create a new buffer to send to the server
            byte[] header = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("rdmstrea"); //Get the bytes of the header
            Buffer.BlockCopy(header, 0, send, 0, header.Length); //Copy the header to the main buffer
            fps = 800;
            Buffer.BlockCopy(img, 0, send, header.Length, img.Length); //Copy the image to the main buffer
            _clientSocket.Send(send, 0, send.Length, SocketFlags.None); //Send the image to the server


        }
```

As you can see as long as the message is only 8 Characters long this works fine. However I want the characters in the message to be variable.

I don't have much knowledge on bytes if im honest so any additional help would be much appreciated.

Thankyou in advance.

Comment: Padding seems incredibly wasteful, why not prefix the data with a single byte representing the length or terminate it with a constant sequence.

Comment: Is the problem calculating size? Try to use [% operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/remainder-operator) and multiplication. Or is the problem of filling allocated byte array with bytes? With zeroes? Then you can clear it (fill with `0`) before copying into it.

Comment: @AlexK.im very new to socket programming. I found this example online and it works but only for set values. Im unsure how you prefix data.

Comment: @Sinatr well calculating size is an issue, im trying to make a monitor application for a school so the can monitior students computers. So each computer is going to have a different DNS.Hostname. I need to be able to identify each screenshare image from the student so i figured adding it in the header is the correct why to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can argue about it if padding is the right way to go, but you could pad the name of your host

```
string hostName = "OhWhatEver".PadRight(100)
```

then use this as input for your GetBytes call.

Edit:
If you can't live with the spaces use that:

```
byte[] header = new byte[100];
byte[] hostname = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("rdmstream§" + System.Net.Dns.GetHostName());
Array.Copy(hostname, header, hostname.Length);
```

Comment: I'll give this a go. Padding just seems like the easiest method for me right now.

Comment: The edit worked on my client, just need to get my server to check through the 100th byte. Thanks for the help @toAtwork

Comment: All hooked up on the server perfectly, been rattling my brain for ages trying to learn this! Really appreciate the help. Thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

If your concern is packet fragmentation: `Socket` has overloads to send a *list* of buffer segments in a single operation. That means you can do something like:

```
var segments = new List<ArraySegment<byte>>();
segments.Add(header);
segments.Add(img);
```

Note that it is not necessary for the header to be the *full* array; you can send a part of an array, which allows you to re-use the same buffer; for example:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[MaxLength];
var segments = new List<ArraySegment<byte>>();
segments.Add(default); // placeholder
segments.Add(img);
foreach(...) {
    string val = ...
    int len = encoding.GetBytes(val, 0, val.Length, buffer, 0);
    segments[0] = new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer, 0, len);
    thisSocket.Send(segments);
}
```

However! to do this usually requires some kind of framing on the header - either a sentinel value (perhaps a trailing CR/LF/CRLF), or a prefix of the number of bytes that are the string - `len` here.

---

If that really isn't possible... just *loop over the unused part of the array* and set it to what you want, or use `Array.Clear` if zero is OK.

Comment: Fragmentation isn't my concern, im trying to create a screen sharing application that monitors multiple client's screens for a school so teachers can monitor there student's work. So each student machine is going to have a seperate DNS name that i need to add to the monitor window to the program knows which computer is which.

Comment: I might be going about it the wrong way so advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: @JeremyGriffin if you're not concerned by packet fragmentation: just make two separate calls to `Send`...  one for the variable header, and one for the fixed payload. Or use the segments approach above.

Comment: I've tried this method also. I have an event to sendstring("Message"); However When i send a string first the picturebox that stores this image doesn't load correctly, im assuming because the server checks for the text received and image received at the same time.